Is there a way to get a NavigationLink to connect and navigate at the same time?
I am building an app for an oil and gas company. The app will be used in the field to connect to and manage devices that inject lubricants into pumps. The app should function as follows: User selects a device to manage from the DeviceListView, the app will navigate to the HomeView where the user can set up the system any way they want to.
The issue I am working on is with the navigation.
As is, my NavigationLink will navigate when the users tap on the green part of the row (blue highlight), but it will not connect with a device. Meaning, all the values to be displayed in HomeView will not show up.
However, when I tap on the text (Red/Orange highlight) the app will connect to the device and load the characteristics in the console, but it will not navigate to the HomeView.
I thought this was a UI issue. I have tried a whole bunch of combinations of H-Stack, Z-stack, modifiers and such, but the result remains the same.
Is there a way to set the NavigationLink to do both, connect and navigate at the same time or with the same tapping gesture? DeviceListView
    import SwiftUI
    import CoreData
    import CoreBluetooth
    import Foundation
    
    //Defines the model for an item in the device list.
    struct DeviceViewItem: Identifiable{
        var id = UUID()
        var uuid: String?
        var sn: String?
        var discovered: Bool
        var name: String?
    }
    
    // Making a shared property to store savedArray
    class DeviceDataManager: ObservableObject {
        static let shared = DeviceDataManager() // Singleton instance
        @Published var savedArray: [DeviceViewItem] = []
    }
    
    struct DeviceListView: View {
        //CoreData vars:
        @FetchRequest(entity: Device.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]) var coreDataDevices: FetchedResults<Device>
        @EnvironmentObject var centralManager: CentralManager
        @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
        
        // State for managing deletion confirmation alert
        @State private var showingDeleteAlert = false
        @State private var deviceToDelete: Device? = nil
    
        var body: some View {
            NavigationStack {
                ZStack{
                    Color("Green 1").ignoresSafeArea()
                    VStack{
                        Image("HeliosLogoSmall")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                            .padding(.top, 40)
                        Text("CONNECT TO A DEVICE")
                            .textStyle(TextStyles.headerBold)
                            .padding()
                    List {
                        let deviceViewList = buildDeviceListView(savedDevice: coreDataDevices, discoveredDevice: centralManager.discoveredPeripherals)
                        ForEach(deviceViewList, id: \.id) { device in
                            NavigationLink(destination: HomeView(), label:{
                                HStack {
                                    Text(device.name ?? "Unknown Device")
                                        .textStyle(TextStyles.display4)
                                }
                                .foregroundColor(device.discovered ? .black : .gray)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    signalConnect(device: device, manager: centralManager)
                                    updateSaveDevice(deviceViewItem: device, context: viewContext)
                                }
                            }
                            )
                            .listRowBackground(Color("Green 1"))
                        }
                        // Swipe to delete functionality
                        .onDelete(perform: showDeleteAlert)
                    }
                    .listStyle(.plain)
                    .font(Font.custom("InstrumentSans-Regular", size:22))
                    .foregroundColor(Color("Grey 5"))
                    .alert(isPresented: $showingDeleteAlert) {
                        Alert(
                            title: Text("Delete Device"),
                            message: Text("Are you sure you want to delete this device? This action cannot be undone."),
                            primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {
                                if let device = deviceToDelete {
                                    deleteDevice(device)
                                }
                            },
                            secondaryButton: .cancel()
                        )
                    }
                    ScanButtonView() //button to begin scanning
                }//Vstack
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)
              }//Zstack
            } //NavigationStack
        }
        
        // Functions to delete a saved device
        
        // Save the context after deleting the device
    }
    
    
    //compares the serial number that we are trying to connect to with the serial number that we have stored
    private func signalConnect(device: DeviceViewItem, manager: CentralManager) {
        print("Tapped " + device.sn!)
        manager.connectBySN(sn: device.sn ?? "Serial1234")
    }
    
    private func buildDeviceListView(savedDevice: FetchedResults<Device>, discoveredDevice: [CBPeripheral] ) -> Array<DeviceViewItem> {
        var savedArray = Array<DeviceViewItem>()
        var discoveredArray = Array<DeviceViewItem>()
        
        // Start by adding all devices from CoreData with discovered = false
        for device in savedDevice {
            var item = DeviceViewItem(discovered: false)
            item.sn = device.serialNumber
            item.uuid = device.uuid
            item.name = device.name
            savedArray.append(item)
        }
        
        // Parse through every discovered device
        for device in discoveredDevice {
            var item = DeviceViewItem(discovered: false)
          //  var item = DeviceViewItem(discovered: true, isConnected: centralManager.isConnected(device.identifier.uuidString)) 
            let sn = CentralManager.buildSn(uuid: device.identifier.uuidString, name: device.name)
            
            // Find out if we've connected to this device before
            // Check if device is present in array
            if let matchIndex = savedArray.firstIndex(where: { $0.sn == sn }) {
                savedArray[matchIndex].discovered = true
            }
            else {
                // We've never saved or connected to this device before, therefore add it to the list.
                item.sn = sn
                item.uuid = device.identifier.uuidString
                item.discovered = true
                item.name = device.name
                discoveredArray.append(item)
            }
        }
        // Update the shared savedArray
        DeviceDataManager.shared.savedArray = savedArray
        
        return savedArray + discoveredArray  //MAKE savedArray value public and accessible to all.
    }


Even if you could use a .simultaneousGesture with a NavigationLink (which I don't believe works), you'd have a logical issue of two independent and simultaneous actions: navigation and connection.
So the problem here is not just a layout or UI issue, but a more fundamental one: navigation should be dependent on connection status and not happen in parallel.
The solution is to use programmatic navigation in order to control the conditions of the navigation. How exactly you will navigate, if at all, depends on your specific use case.
Here's a simplified working example using programmatic navigation, where clicking a device triggers a mock function that returns a connection success bool (based on odd/even device id numbers):

If the connection is "successful", navigation gets triggered.
If not, an error is displayed and navigation doesn't happen.

import SwiftUI

//Routes for programatic navigation
enum NavigateConnectRoute: Hashable {
    case home, devices
}

//Observable singleton
@Observable
class DeviceDataManager {
    var deviceID: Int?
    static let shared = DeviceDataManager() // Singleton instance
    private init() {}
}

//Main view
struct NavigateConnect: View {
    
    //State values
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    @State private var showError: Bool = false
    @State private var errorDeviceID: Int?
    
    //Bindings
    @Bindable var deviceManager: DeviceDataManager = .shared
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            VStack {
                
                Text("Select a device:")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                
                List {
                    ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { id in
                        Button {
                            
                            //Simulate connection to a device (odd numbers fail, even numbers succeed)
                            let connected = connect(deviceID: id, status: id % 2 == 0 ? true : false)
                            
                            if connected {
                                //Display console message
                                print("Connection successful for device \(id)")
                                
                                //Navigate to Home view programmatically
                                path.append(NavigateConnectRoute.home)
                            }
                            else {
                                //Show error
                                errorDeviceID = id
                            }
                        } label : {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Device \(id)")
                                    .foregroundStyle(errorDeviceID == id ? .red : .primary)
                                Spacer()
                                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                                    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                            }
                        }
                        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                        .tint(.black)
                    }
                }
                .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                .background(Color.clear)
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .onChange(of: errorDeviceID) {
                if errorDeviceID != nil {
                    showError = true
                }
            }
            .alert(
                "Connection Error",
                isPresented: $showError,
                presenting: errorDeviceID
            ) { id in
                Button("OK", role: .cancel) {
                    print("Showed error alert for device \(id)")
                }
            } message: { id in
                Text("Unable to connect to device \(id)")
            }
            .padding(.top, 50)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .background{
                Color.yellow
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Connect")
            .navigationDestination(for: NavigateConnectRoute.self) { route in
                switch route {
                    case .home: NavigateConnectHome()
                    case .devices: NavigateConnect()
                }
            }
        }
        .tint(.black)
    }
    
    //Helper function to simulate connecting to a device and returning a connection status
    private func connect(deviceID: Int, status: Bool) -> Bool {
        
        //Display console message
        print("Connection to device \(deviceID) was \(status ? "successful" : "unsuccessful")")

        //Set singleton observer value with the device id
        deviceManager.deviceID = status ? deviceID : nil
        
        //Return simulated status
        return status
    }
}

//Device home view
struct NavigateConnectHome: View {
    
    //Binding to singleton observable
    @Bindable var deviceManager: DeviceDataManager = .shared

    //Body
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is home view for device \(deviceManager.deviceID ?? -1) ")
        }
        .navigationTitle("Home")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        .background{
            Color.yellow
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
        .onDisappear {
            //Reset device id when leaving home view
            deviceManager.deviceID = nil
        }
    }
}

//Preview
#Preview {
    NavigateConnect()
}



